# Twitter search api request fails with international charcters

Tags: php, mysql, api, twitter, utf-8

I'm using the [TwitterAPIExchange](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/blob/master/TwitterAPIExchange.php) wrapper to retrieve tweets from the twitter search api. It works fine as long as I don't use the sewdish characters å, ä, ö.

My code is simply this:

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$getfield = '?q='.$twittername.'&lang=sv';
$requestMethod = 'GET';

$response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                ->performRequest();
```

When I echo out `$twittername`, I can see that the name is correct swedish, but in the response from twitter the query that twitter receives is using replacement characters. For example: A request for the name `Göran`, becomes `G%EF%BF%BDran`.

I have set my datbase to utf-8 general.

I have also tried to urlencode the characters å, ä, ö (with `%E5`, `%E4`, `%F6` ), but the query that twitter receives remains the same, ie `G%EF%BF%BDran`.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `rawurlencode()` on `$twittername`?

if "the query that twitter receives remains the same" is true, then surely it is the API's responsibility to convert it into UTF-8? when you use a RESTful API then url encoding should be expected.

if *you* are having problems with `G%EF%BF%BDran` (and not twitter) you can always `urldecode()` it.